# How to get id of a button from view to model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and facing problem in getting the id of a button from my view to the model. I am looping through buttons and the name of every button is coming from database which is unique for each iteration. how could i recognize the button in my model?
This is the code for my VIEW..

```
foreach($detail1 as $object)
{

 input type='submit' class='btn' name='$object->p_id' value='VIEW'

}
```

When I want to retrieve the Id of a button in model i do like..

```
$abc = $this->input->post('??? what to do inside?');
```

Please help me out..

Comment: `$this->input->post('FIELD_NAME');`

Comment: Can you show your code more?

Comment: But what would be the field name? as i dont know the field name

Comment: product_description is my model
VIEW:-
detail1 is the objct of database containing unique product id for each btn
<?php echo form_open('site/product_description'); ?>
foreach($detail1 as $object)
{
    <input type='submit' class='btn' name='$object->p_id' value='VIEW'/> 
}
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
-------
now in MODEL i want to get the id of the button being pressed only..
one way is to get the id by $this->input->post(and here we have to write the name of a button.. but in my case i dont know which button is pressed so i actually dont know the name of the button pressed to be entered here)

Answer (score 1):

You can use input arrays -

```
name='ids[<?php echo $object->p_id;]'
```

And in model -

```
$abc_ids = $this->input->post('ids');
```

`$abc_ids` will be the array of `id`s